# Does every orthocomplemented lattice satisfy the shuffle laws?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $L=(X,\wedge,\vee,^\bot)$ denote a non-empty lattice having a unary operation $x \mapsto x^\bot$ that satisfies both "shuffle" laws: $$x \wedge y \leq z \iff x \leq y^\bot \vee z.$$

$$x \leq y \vee z \iff x \wedge y^\bot \leq z.$$

Then $L$ is an orthocomplemented lattice. (Proof below).

**Question.** Does every orthocomplemented lattice satisfy the shuffle laws? It suffices to prove just one of them, but I've been unable to do so.

---

*Proof of claim.*

**Complements.** Let $x$ be fixed but arbitrary. This is allowed, since $L$ was assumed non-empty. We will show that $x^\bot \wedge x$ is a least element. TFAE.

1. $x^\bot \wedge x \leq a$
2. $x^\bot \leq x^\bot \vee a$
3. TRUE

Thus $x^\bot \wedge x$ is a least element. A similar argument shows that $x^\bot \vee x$ is a maximum element.

**Involutiveness.** We will show that $x \leq x^{\bot\bot}.$ TFAE.

1. $x \leq a$
2. $x \wedge x \leq a$
3. $x \leq x^\bot \vee a$
4. $x \wedge x^{\bot\bot} \leq a$

So the elements above $x$ and $x \wedge x^{\bot\bot}$ are identical; by antisymmetry, $x = x \wedge x^{\bot\bot}$. It follows that $x \leq x^{\bot\bot}.$

A similar argument shows the other direction; therefore $x = x^{\bot\bot}.$

**Order-reversingness.** The following are equivalent.

1. $x \leq y$
2. $x \wedge 1 \leq y$
3. $1 \leq x^\bot \vee y$
4. $1 \wedge y^\bot \leq x^\bot$
5. $y^\bot \leq x^\bot$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

[image: Hexagon]

Put $x=a^\perp$, $y=b^\perp$, $z=b$. The first shuffle law fails.

But this makes the whole thing more interesting. Maybe the shuffle 
laws imply orthomodularity?

Comment: Good answer. I'll let you know if I have any ideas.

Comment: Yes, they imply orthomodularity and even distributivity, so $L$ must be a Boolean algebra.  Indeed, by the first shuffle law, $L$ must be a Heyting algebra/Brouwerian lattice, which is necessarily distributive.